# AOSP : Unkown C++ headers ( no such file or directory for <vector>, <iostream>, .. >

Tags: android, c++, build, iostream, android-source

I've downloaded the Android Tree and succeeded to compile an run it on a device. After that, I added some C++ files and I got error like:  no such file or directory.
I tried to add the libstlport_static but that did not work for me, I think I haven't implemented it in the right way.

I hope you could help me  with that. Thanks!

---

Makefile (from comment)

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libstlport

include external/stlport/libstlport.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/sources.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := myLib
LOCAL_CLFAGS := -std=c99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: What does your source file(s) look like? Have a (small) example to show us? And more importantly, what does your makefile look like?

Comment: my make file is the following 
'LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libstlport
include external/stlport/libstlport.mk
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/sources.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := myLib

LOCAL_CLFAGS := -std=c99 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1
LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)'

the source files were compiled and tested using JNI, I had'nt got a problem because I had just to add a line to the Application.mk specifying that I am using stl_port but here with aosp there is no Application.mk  file !

Answer (score 0):

It was the order of adding these two lines :

"LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libstlport

include external/stlport/libstlport.mk"

So, I managed to not use the libstlport and instead I've used android::Vector and for the string I replaced it with char*.